# response is null in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, xml, wcf-rest

I want to call rest services using javascript. My code is:

```
function CreateXMLHttpRequest() {
   if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
      alert("1");
      return new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else if (typeof ActiveXObject != "undefined") {
      alert("2");
      return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   else {
      throw new Error("XMLHttpRequestnot supported");
   }
}

function CallWebService() {
   var objXMLHttpRequest = null;
   objXMLHttpRequest = CreateXMLHttpRequest();

   objXMLHttpRequest.open("POST", "http://localhost:2546/abc.svc/json/GetXml", true);
   objXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml;charset=UTF-16");
   var packet = '<CompanyRequest xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/abc.DomainModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><CompanyName>company</CompanyName></CompanyRequest>';

   objXMLHttpRequest.send(packet);
      alert(packet);
      var d =(objXMLHttpRequest.responseText);
      alert(d);           
   }
```

It is working fine in IE, but in Firefox and chrome the response is empty. I can't understand what is going wrong. I have been searching for this for 3 days. 
Let me know if there are any errors.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

You're making async call. Try to use callback.

```
function CreateXMLHttpRequest() {
     if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
         return new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else if (typeof ActiveXObject != "undefined") {
         return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     } else {
         throw new Error("XMLHttpRequestnot supported");
     }
 }
 function CallWebService() {
     var objXMLHttpRequest = CreateXMLHttpRequest();
     objXMLHttpRequest.open("POST", "http://localhost:2546/abc.svc/json/GetXml", true);
     objXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
     var packet = '<CompanyRequest xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/abc.DomainModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><CompanyName>company</CompanyName></CompanyRequest>';
     objXMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (){
         if (objXMLHttpRequest.readyState==4 && objXMLHttpRequest.status==200) {
             alert(objXMLHttpRequest.responseText);
         }
     }
     objXMLHttpRequest.send(packet);
 }
```

Comment: wats the error ur getting? R u getting the xml in the server side?

Comment: no error it is displaying?just empty alert box...it is working in IE but not in chrome and firefox

Comment: Try setting the Content-Type to "text/xml". Check the edited code in CallWebservice function.

Comment: I'm not able to understand the cause. U may ping me at sathishp123@gmail.com

Comment: I replied to ur id. Check it.

Comment: In chrome the status is becoming 0 wha is the reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an async request.

Try doing a synchronous request like

```
 objXMLHttpRequest.open("POST", "http://localhost:2546/abc.svc/json/GetXml", false);
```

Or asynchronusely

```
objXMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if ( objXMLHttpRequest.readyState == 4 ) {
        alert(req.responseText);
    }
};
```

And set the header to:

Try this:

```
 objXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

 objXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader( "SOAPAction", "http://localhost:2546/abc.svc/json/GetXml" );
```

Comment: This will work. But it'll freeze the UI from doing any other actions until the response comes.

Comment: @Vidhya: Sorry. Just wrote a raw code. I always use variable name 'req' for XMLHttpRequest.  Updated.

Comment: no error it is displaying?just empty alert box...it is working in IE but not in chrome and firefox

Comment: Did you try to do it synchronously? Use my first option to test. If the alert box is still empty, then you might want to check your server side code.

Comment: Try this: 
objXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

objXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader( "SOAPAction", "http://localhost:2546/abc.svc/json/GetXml" );